# Supporting Different Screen Orientation & Different drawable images for multi screens

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

How can I understand to implement different layout,drawable for different screen orientation ? If you have any example regarding this please post here. And also for inserting icons in my layout I will have to insert for all sizes ?? How to do that ?

[I read Google documentation but it doesn't solved my problem!](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

I need an example to understand.Kindly help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google library `PercentRelativeLayout` with this `library` you can set `width`, `height` and `margin` of your `views` by percentage which is great because in all screen they look the same(for your case they look good for `landscape` and `portrait` screen orientation) and of course it is not hard to code it. Here example:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <ImageView
         app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
         app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
         app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
         app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"/>
 </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

you must add this line in your build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.2.0'
}
```

**Official documentation by Google** https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html

Hope this help for your case!

Comment: Thanks a lot Buddy !

Comment: If my answer is help you to achive your goal you can accept it ! Im glad ti help you!